# SqlAlchemy AttributeError: 'category' object has no attribute 'subcategories'

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, sqlalchemy

I am using python (django) with sqlalchemy. I created these two paintings related to each other.

```
def CreateDynamicSubCategories():
    try:
        category_subcategory = Table('category_subcategory', Base.metadata,
                Column('category_id', Integer, ForeignKey('category.id')),
                Column('subcategory_id', Integer, ForeignKey('subcategory.id')),
            __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
            )
    except Exception as e:
        GetErrorDetails(e)
    
    
    class Category(Base):
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 
        __tablename__ = 'category'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
        subcategories = relationship("Subcategory", secondary=category_subcategory, back_populates="categories")
        products = relationship("Product", back_populates="category")

    class Subcategory(Base):
        __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 
        __tablename__ = 'subcategory'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
        categories = relationship("Category", secondary=category_subcategory, back_populates="subcategories")
        products = relationship("Product", back_populates="subcategory")
```

The problem is that I wanted to add a new table with the following codes:

```
 Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    # Adding category
    new_category = Category(name="Electronics")
    session.add(new_category)
    session.commit()

    new_subcategory = Subcategory(name="Smartphones")
    session.add(new_subcategory)
    session.commit()

    new_category.subcategories.append(new_subcategory)
    session.commit()

    new_subcategory.categories.append(new_category)
    session.commit()
```

I encounter an error like this:

`new_category.subcategories.append(new_subcategory) AttributeError: 'category' object has no attribute 'subcategories'`
What is the problem here? Can someone who knows please help?

I continued to get the same mistakes even after the chatgpt help. Can someone who knows the problem say?

Comment: Why do you have that `try/except` logic ? Also how do you create/extend the tables ? If I use your table and classes it works for me.

Comment: @ljmc Because I saving error and bugs than creating logics. And i want send some error text to enduser.  
I am using this function for extend table:
```
   engine.execute('ALTER TABLE %s ADD COLUMN %s %s' %
                    (table_name, column_name, column_type))
```